# Match List of objects against list of properties

Tags: java, junit, matcher, hamcrest

I'm trying to use hamcrest matchers to match a list of objects against a list/array of their properties. For one property value this is not a problem, because I can do something like this:

```
assertThat(savedGroup.getMembers(),
    containsInAnyOrder(hasProperty("name", is(NAMES[0]))));
```

For multiple property values I can use multiple hasProperty() calls

```
assertThat(savedGroup.getMembers(),
    containsInAnyOrder(
        hasProperty("name", is(NAMES[0])),
        hasProperty("name", is(NAMES[1]))));
```

But is there a generic way to match against all values in the NAMES array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way (IMO) to do this would be to combine the overloaded `containsInAnyOrder` Matcher along with a custom `FeatureMatcher`.  Ultimately your code would look like this:

```
String[] expectedNames = new String[] { "John", "Bob", "Carol"};
assertThat(savedGroup.getMembers(), hasNames(expectedNames));
```

`hasNames` is implemented as follows:

```
private Matcher<Iterable<? extends Member>> hasNames(String[] expectedNames) {
    return containsInAnyOrder(Arrays.stream(expectedNames).map(name -> name(name)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

And the final part is the call to `name` which generates a Matcher that will extract a property in a type-safe way from your object:

```
private Matcher<Member> name(String name) {
    return new FeatureMatcher<Member, String>(equalTo(name), "name", "name") {
        @Override
        protected String featureValueOf(Member actual) {
            return actual.getName();
        }
    };
}
```

The benefit of doing it this is way is that:

- You get the benefit of type-safety instead of using `hasProperty`
- Your test now describes what you actual want to match on, i.e. `hasNames`
- The code produced is now more flexible and composable.  Want to match a single objects name? All you now need to do is `assertThat(member, has(name("Fred")))`

You can get even more composability by moving the `equalTo` sub-matcher to be part of the hasNames call like this:

```
private Matcher<Iterable<? extends Member>> hasNames(String[] expectedNames) {
    return containsInAnyOrder(Arrays.stream(expectedNames).map(name -> name(equalTo(name))).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}

private Matcher<Member> name(Matcher<String> nameMatcher) {
    return new FeatureMatcher<Member, String>(nameMatcher, "name", "name") {
        @Override
        protected String featureValueOf(Member actual) {
            return actual.getName();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of `containsInAnyOrder`'s overloads accepts a collection of matchers as its argument. Thus you could do something like this:

```
assertThat(
    savedGroup.getMembers(),
    containsInAnyOrder(
        Stream.of(NAMES)
              .map(name -> hasProperty("name", is(name)))
              .collect(Collectors.toList()) 
    ));
```

(if using Java 8, otherwise would need to add a loop building up the collection)

Answer (score 0):

Need to make some cleanup (description output), but I think it does solve your problem:

```
package org.example.matchers;

import java.util.List;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Factory;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;

public class ContainsArrayElementsInAnyOrder<T> extends TypeSafeMatcher<List<T>> {

    private T[] toMatch;

    public ContainsArrayElementsInAnyOrder(final T[] toMatch) {
        this.toMatch = toMatch;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(List<T> item) {
        if(item.size() != toMatch.length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (T t : toMatch) {
            if(!item.contains(t)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeMismatchSafely(List<T> item, Description mismatchDescription) {
        mismatchDescription.appendValueList("[", ",", "]", item);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendValueList("[", ",", "]", toMatch);
    }

    @Factory
    public static <T> ContainsArrayElementsInAnyOrder<T> containsArrayElementsInAnyOrder(T[] elements) {
        return new ContainsArrayElementsInAnyOrder<T>(elements);
    }    


}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void shouldContainsInAnyOrderSameElementsInArrayAsInList() {
    final String[] NAME = new String[]{"name3", "name1", "name2"};

    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(3);
    result.add("name2");
    result.add("name1");
    result.add("name4");

    assertThat(result, containsArrayElementsInAnyOrder(NAME));
}
```

Output if not match:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: ["name3","name1","name2"]
     but: ["name2","name1","name4"]
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:923)
    at ..
```